# How can I encrypt a plaintext with given key and iv using AES-128-CTR in python 3.7?

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to use python 3.7.3 to encrypt a given plaintext with a given key and a given iv. I am unfamiliar with python encryption libraries but have looked around for a couple hours trying to figure this out, and I am unable to.

I have tired using the pycryptodome library as I have been unable to use crypto and pycrypto (keep getting errors when I install them, maybe because I am on windows?).

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util import Counter

data = b"plaintext"
key = b"5A557AC90890B2ACD59C536FE4279BBC"
iv = b"5A557AC90890B2ACD59C536FE4279BBC"

counter = Counter.new(128, initial_value=iv)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=counter)

enc = cipher.encrypt(data)

print(enc)
```

My end result is to print out the encrypted string, but currently I am getting various errors such as "not supported between instances of 'bytes' and 'int'"

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not use **[`Counter`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Util.Counter-module.html)** correctly. You are trying to use hexidecimal where an integer should be, and even if you converted your `iv` value to an integer it would be too large.

> **initial_value** (*integer*) - The initial value of the counter. Default
>   value is 1.

So changing the code to the following would work for example:

```
counter = Counter.new(128, initial_value=1)
```

If you want to randomize the `iv` you could do something such as:

```
iv = int.from_bytes(os.urandom(16), sys.byteorder)
counter = Counter.new(128, initial_value=iv)
```